# How to draw LineChartData in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, ios-charts

I switched to swift 3 and I am now struggling to get my chart data shown again. When I use it like that, I just see an empty chart.
I think some initializers changed?

I am using the Swift-3.0 branch.

```
@IBOutlet weak var lineChartView: LineChartView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

  for x in data {
    ...
    let dataSet = LineChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: player.getName())
    lineChartData.addDataSet(dataSet)
  }

  lineChartView.data = lineChartData
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40376720/how-to-use-xaxis-with-label-in-charts-frameworks?rq=1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They changed the way, how is data constructed. Enclosed please find following sample:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let dollars1 = [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0, 16.0, 4.0, 18.0, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0, 4.0]
    let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    // 1 - creating an array of data entries
    var yValues : [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry]()

    for i in 0 ..< months.count {
        yValues.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i + 1), y: dollars1[i]))
    }

    let data = LineChartData()
    let ds = LineChartDataSet(values: yValues, label: "Months")

    data.addDataSet(ds)
    self.lineChartView.data = data
}
```

Comment: This will put Doubles on the xAxis label. How do I get the months?