# How to show json data in line chart using swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, linechart

I am trying to design an ios app to display json data in a line chart.

First of all, this is my json data.

```
{
TH_5min: [
{
Data: "2019-02-23T00:00:00",
Time: "11:00:00",
XTP_A: 10.5, //temperature 1
XHP_A: 11.5, //humidity 1
XTP_B: 33.5,
XHP_B: 44.6,
XTP_C: 88.9,
XHP_C: 66.6,
XTP_D: 77.9,
XHP_D: 99.6,
XTP_E: 87.87,
XHP_E: 66.66
},
{
Data: "2019-02-23T00:00:00",
Time: "11:05:00",
XTP_A: 55.2,  //temperature 1
XHP_A: 44.3,  //humidity 1
XTP_B: 66.6,
XHP_B: 77.87,
XTP_C: 87.77,
XHP_C: 87.87,
XTP_D: 8.87,
XHP_D: 78.78,
XTP_E: 87.78,
XHP_E: 87.87
}
]
}
```

This is my implementation of the swift code showing json data.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      apiip = APIip
        getlatestTh_5min()
    @objc func getlatestTh_5min(){
        guard let th_5minUrl = URL(string: "http://" + apiip + "/api/Th_5min") else{
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: th_5minUrl)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data,response,error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            if let data = data {
                self.th_5mins = self.pardrJsonData(data: data)
                self.getchat()
            }
        })
        task.resume()
        //getchat()
    }
    func pardrJsonData(data: Data) -> [Th_5min]{
        var th_5mins = [Th_5min]()
        do {
            let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            let jsonTh_5mins = jsonResult?["TH_5min"] as! [AnyObject]
            print(jsonTh_5mins)
            print(th_5mins.count)
            for jsonTh_5min in jsonTh_5mins{
                var th_5min = Th_5min()
                th_5min.Data = jsonTh_5min["Data"] as! String
                th_5min.Time = jsonTh_5min["Time"] as! String
                th_5min.XTP_A = jsonTh_5min["XTP_A"] as! Double
                th_5min.XHP_A = jsonTh_5min["XHP_A"] as! Double
                print(th_5min)
                th_5mins.append(th_5min)
                //getchat()
            }        }catch{
                print(error)
        }
        //getchat()
        return th_5mins

    }
```

This is how I draw the line chart, using swift code.

```
@objc func getchat(){

        chartView = LineChartView()  
        chartView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 80, width: self.view.bounds.width-20,height: self.view.bounds.height-100)
        self.view.addSubview(chartView)
        var dataEntries1 = [ChartDataEntry]()
        for i in 0..<th_5mins.count {
            chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: [th_5mins[i].Time])
            let y = th_5mins[i].XTP_A
            let entry = ChartDataEntry.init(x: Double(i), y: Double(y))
            dataEntries1.append(entry)
        }
        let chartDataSet1 = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries1, label: "temperature")

        chartDataSet1.colors = [NSUIColor.red]

        var dataEntries2 = [ChartDataEntry]()
        for i in 0..<th_5mins.count {
            chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: [th_5mins[i].Time])
            let y = th_5mins[i].XHP_A
            let entry = ChartDataEntry.init(x: Double(i), y: Double(y))
            dataEntries2.append(entry)

        }
        let chartDataSet2 = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries2, label: "humidity")
        chartDataSet2.colors = [NSUIColor.black]

        let chartData = LineChartData(dataSets: [chartDataSet1, chartDataSet2])

        chartView.data = chartData
    }
}
```

This is the result of my work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubzpu.png)

Although the json data is successfully displayed, I don't know why it is loading for a long time, and I hope that the "time" in my json data can be displayed on the X axis above, marked with my temperature and humidity, and cannot be successful.
I also hope that my line chart view can be implemented as a layout.

Comment: are providing data like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39770862/1142743

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. "I don't know why it is loading for a long time". Do you mean that the graph does not load immediately upon opening the view? This is because the data is loading asynchronously from a remote source (correctly now, well done). It may well take a few seconds for your JSON to download over the web. That is ok. You can test the endpoint in a browser and see how long the response takes.
2. "I hope that the 'time' in my json data can be displayed on the X axis above". Yes. You can take the assignation of `IndexAxisValueFormatter` outside of the loop and you should pass all labels as `values` into the constructor. Try this code, replacing the equivalent loop:-

   ```
   var labels: [String] = []
   for i in 0..<th_5mins.count {
       let y = th_5mins[i].XTP_A
       let entry = ChartDataEntry.init(x: Double(i), y: Double(y))
       dataEntries1.append(entry)
       labels.append(th_5mins[i].Time)
   }
   chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: labels)
   ```

Note that the method you use for plotting against dates will result in an evenly spread graph, irrespective of your time gaps (e.g. if readings are 5 mins apart between the first two, but 5 years apart for the next two, they will still appear with even gaps between them.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and explanation, but I still don't understand how to adjust my swift code, how do I use this new class?

Comment: Where have you defined IndexAxisValueFormatter? You are using it in your code already. Replace it with mine.

Comment: for i in 0..<th_5mins.count {
            class IndexAxisValueFormatter: NSObject, IndexAxisValueFormatter {
                func stringforvalue(value: Double , axis: AxisBase?) -> String { let i = round(Double)
                    return th_5mins[i].Time
                }
            }
            //chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: [th_5mins[i].Time])
            let y = th_5mins[i].XTP_A
            let entry = ChartDataEntry.init(x: Double(i), y: Double(y))
            
            dataEntries1.append(entry)
        } .          I

Comment: I just replace  chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: [th_5mins[i].Time]) to  class IndexAxisValueFormatter: NSObject, IndexAxisValueFormatter {
                func stringforvalue(value: Double , axis: AxisBase?) -> String { let i = round(Double)
                    return th_5mins[i].Time
                }
            }

Comment: No. Revert to your code as above. Hold Command and click on IndexAxisValueFormatter. Go to definition. You must have defined it somewhere. Replace its definition - not its usage - with mine. If not, put the definition I gave outside of your `getchat` function. Change the `chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter =` line exactly as I've shown you in the answer.

Comment: understood! I went to the definition of IndexAxisValueFormatter. There was a lot of code in it. I replaced it with your method, but it shows such an error.
1.Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
2.Method 'stringForValue(_:axis:)' must be declared public because it matches a requirement in public protocol 'IAxisValueFormatter'Mark the instance method as 'public' to satisfy the requirement
3.Use of unresolved identifier 'th_5mins'

Comment: If i add new class outside of my getchat getchat still have some error.1.Instance member 'th_5mins' of type 'linechartViewController' cannot be used on instance of nested type 'linechartViewController.IndexAxisValueFormatter' 2.Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

Comment: You're right - ok, then put my code just above the `getchat` function. Rename it so as not to cause a name clash (DateAxisValueFormatter) and then use `chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = DateAxisValueFormatter(th_5mins)`. It needs to use the `th_5mins` array. Accept the array in the constructor. Alternatively, make your view controller conform to IAxisValueFormatter and make the `stringForValue` a member function.

Comment: 1. put  class DataAxisValueFormatter: NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter {
        func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String { let i = round(value); return th_5mins[i].Time } }    outside of my getchat()       2. replace  chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values:[th_5mins[i].Time]) to chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = DataAxisValueFormatter()  when i done those step still show Instance member 'th_5mins' of type 'linechartViewController' cannot be used on instance of nested type 'linechartViewController.DataAxisValueFormatter' in my new class

Comment: I am very sorry, I have not studied swift, thank you for your patience.

Comment: If you can, can you teach me the steps of fixing from start?plesae.

Comment: Accept the array in the constructor. Alternatively, make your view controller conform to IAxisValueFormatter and make the stringForValue a member function. I don't understand what this means.What should I do in my swift code?

Comment: Ok. Reworked the answer. Ignore the previous work about rewriting IndexAxisValueFormatter. Return to the original code and follow the new answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patient explanation, I solved my problem! But I still don't understand how code is used. If you can, can you tell me how you know how to use these codes?

Comment: Years of experience, reading the docs, following StackOverflow, studying tutorials.... Find a good tutorial site and do lots of work. Ray Wenderlich is good IMO. That's all I can do to help. But read a lot more about swift and coding before asking questions on here.

Comment: I have a question. You said that json data will not be displayed immediately, but I open the view and the loading time is about 8~15 seconds. Is this normal? My other pages are also displayed in the view cell using json. The response time is less than one second. Is there a problem with the code I am drawing line chart?

Comment: Is not beyond the realms of possibility. Open a web browser on the API page (`"http://" + apiip + "/api/Th_5min"`) and see how long the page takes to load. It will be a few seconds probably. Your app will experience this delay too.

Comment: Ok! Thank you so much! Thank you again for your help.